# Handle hidden elements in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm developing a selenium application using web driver, And I am facing a general problem with handle hidden elements in Selenium WebDriver. Please help me out to resolve it. Any kind of help we appreciate.

I'm trying with this code

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Have no idea why this question got so many upvotes as it's totally unclear what exactly is wrong with code.. @Manish Mishra , so what is your question? Your current code should deal with your problem (of course if `element` is already defined WebElement). What kind of *help* you're searching for?

Comment: I am using above code @Andersson but sometimes it fails. I don't know why? but I am facing the problem with it.

Comment: What problem and how can the accepted answer solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it may solve your problem:

```
(JavascriptExecutor(driver)).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName(ElementLocator)[0].click();");
```

Comment: Actually, this is exactly the same solution as provided in answer. Even worst as this code is obviously NOT WORKING. Note that `getElementsByClassName()` returns a *list* of elements that has no `click()` method